# Код работает правильно но после правильного ответа также выводит и свое возмущение, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, range

У нас есть файл з сотрудниками в котором инфа о них а вот сам код:

```
     def workers():
        infile = open("C:/Users/OWNER/Desktop/2/workers.txt","r")
        arr = []
        arr1 = []
        
        arr = infile.readlines()
        
        for i in arr:
            arr1.append(i.split(","))
        
        #------------task 1--------
        for i in arr1:
            if(35>(2017-int(i[4]))):
                print(i[1], "-", 2017-int(i[4]),"годика")
    workers()
```

После запуска программы результат выводит правильный, но также выводит и ошибку:

```
Юрий С.О. - 22 годика
Мария Ф. Н.- 19 годика
```

это правильный ответ о котором я говорила выше а за ним и ошибочка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\2\Lab.py", line 20, in <module>
    workers()
  File "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\2\Lab.py", line 13, in workers
    if(35>(2017-int(i[4]))):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Как можно заметить оно и так работает но очень бы хотелось убрать это ошибку также когда игралась с кодом заметила что если вставить return ошибка уходит но выводит уже только одну персону возраст которой подходит под условие

Answer (score 1):

Содержимое файла `workers.txt` приходится додумывать так что код может потребовать адаптации.
Немного переписал Вашу реализацию:

```py
def worker():
    with open("asd.txt","r") as f:
        lst = f.readlines()

    for i in lst:
        if i and i != "\n":
            s = i.split(" ") # разбить строку по пробелу
            a = 2017 - int(s[4])
            if 35 > a :
                print(s[1], "-", a,"годика")
worker()
```

1. Ошибка скорее всего из за пустых строк в конце файла, что решается проверкой `if i and i != "\n":`. Можно просто добавить ее в Ваш код, что скорее всего должно решить проблему.
2. В моей реализации строка разбивается по пробелу `s = i.split(" ")` подставьте актуальное разбитие для вашего файла.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, очень благодарна)